# TinyMCE discrepancy in the font size toolbar dropdown

Tags: tinymce

In the drop-down for font sizes in TinyMCE it looks like this.

[image]

Notice that it is using the unit px in the header when the rest all say pt. Any way of fixing it so instead of px it reads pt?

Also, why is it so wide?

Update: I tried overriding the font size list, which worked, but didn't help with the label being "px" or the width.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the site default font size, from the site's CSS, was 11pt. I added 11pt, the to the font size toolbar which clarified the UI. It now shows up instead of 14px in the toolbar, and selecting text and clicking on the toolbar shows 11 pt selected.